# Loading Fragment in Compose, it called commit several times

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

I tried to load a Fragment in Compose as below, through the `supportFragmentManager` as shown below.

```
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AndroidViewBinding(FragmentContainerBinding::inflate) {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(container.id, MyFragment()).commit()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when the view is shown, the fragment gets committed (loaded) several times (i.e. the `onCreate()` is called several times)

Any way to prevent committing several times?
Is there a way to resume the state as well (e.g. in case got killed by the system, how to get it restored)?

(note: I'm not using the `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` in the XML as in [Developer Doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#fragments-in-compose) I do have different fragments per some logic (not shown here), hence I'll have to use `supportFragmentManager`)

Comment: This might address the question https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/load-fragments-in-jetpack-compose-beyond-what-google-taught-356a7981268d?sk=43b363c34040c646454d1629ef5f504b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way to get this working

```
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            FragmentContainer(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
                commit = { add(it, MyFragment()) }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FragmentContainer(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    commit: FragmentTransaction.(containerId: Int) -> Unit
) {
    val containerId by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(View.generateViewId()) }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            fragmentManager.findFragmentById(containerId)?.view
                ?.also { (it.parent as? ViewGroup)?.removeView(it) }
                ?: FragmentContainerView(context)
                    .apply { id = containerId }
                    .also {
                        fragmentManager.commit { commit(it.id) }
                    }
        }
    )
}
```

Note this will need Fragment's KTX

```
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1"
```

Comment: The above is quite okay, but a more complete solution is in https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/load-fragments-in-jetpack-compose-beyond-what-google-taught-356a7981268d?sk=43b363c34040c646454d1629ef5f504b

Comment: It doesn't allow to import `fragmentContainerView`.  Unresolved reference.